# How to mimic html select box

Tags: html, css, html-select

I want to have a normal html select but instead of text have css/images. Now I know this can't be done in any browser except Firefox but I'd like to know if there is a way around this **without** using JavaScript. My website has to display on feature phones (i.e. not smartphones) and the JavaScript doesn't work on those them. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What browser are you running on these phones?

Comment: It varies, some run opera mini, others run the native browsers on the devices

Comment: You can certainly emulate the presentation of a select box without JavaScript (to varying degrees of accuracy) but you won't be able to emulate its function without JavaScript. So, you'll either have to use 'just text' (for most browsers) or require JavaScript (which, apparently, you can't).

Comment: The reason for all this is I wanted to have a 5 star rating system on my website. Now with the hovers over the stars the browsers still couldn't handle it. So I thought of having images/css as the stars in a html select. But that isn't do able... So is there any way of having a 5 star rating system that isn't to flashy so that the browsers can handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours working at this I found a reasonable solution. If you want "images" to appear in your html select simply use font-face. So download a font online that has a star in its alphabet. Then use the following in the css. Make sure your url path is correct:

```
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
        src: url('../css/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../css/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../css/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../css/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../css/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
        }

    #Condition
    {
        font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    }
```

Then in your html select have the following:

```
<select id = "Condition">
      <option >R</option>
      <option >RR</option>
      <option >RRR</option>
      <option >RRRR</option>
      <option >RRRRR</option>
</select>
```

We use R because R is the letter that represents a star in this given font. Also have a look at the following [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/). it really helped